# How to delete attr_accessor in ruby

Tags: ruby, attr-accessor

In ruby, if I have a class `greet` and has method `say_hi` that prints out `"Hello #{@name}"` when name is a instance variable of class `greet`, and I allow access to `@name` by adding in the `attr_accessor :name`, so now I can directly change `@name`.

But how do I remove this `attr_accessor` if I no longer want people to be able to change `@name` directly?

Comment: You mean after name gets set you want to remove the ability?

Comment: You cannot have a class that starts with a lower letter.

Answer (score 5):

You cannot have a class `greet`, so I suppose you have something else, say `A`.

```
class A
  undef :name
  undef :name=
end
```