# Revoking instance variable set on rendering_controller (render_anywhere gem)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems

This specific use case of this question may warrent a github issue, but my question is broader than just the specific use case as you'll see, so bear with me!

I am using the [`render_anywhere`](https://rubygems.org/gems/render_anywhere) gem in a project, and I have found a situation where I need to revoke an instance variable which is set inside of a loop before the next iteration occurs (the object which uses `render_anywhere` exists outside the loop so the variable remains in scope).

I'd rather avoid having to re-initialize the object for each iteration of the loop if possible.

The `set_instance_variable` method works as shown below (taken from [rubydoc](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/render_anywhere/0.0.12/RenderAnywhere#set_instance_variable-instance_method)):

```
# File 'lib/render_anywhere.rb', line 20

def set_instance_variable(var, value)
  rendering_controller.class_eval do
    attr_accessor :"#{var}"
  end
  rendering_controller.public_send("#{var}=", value)
end
```

So I would imagine I need to remove the `attr_accessor` using something along the lines of the method described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18235690/how-to-delete-attr-accessor-in-ruby):

```
undef :"#{var}"
undef :"#{var}="
```

So my question really is twofold:

1. Is the above the best way to remove the attribute read/write methods from the `rendering_controller` once the instance variable has been set?
2. Does `attr_accessor` do anything else that `undef` will not 'clean up'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`attr_accessor` is a "macro" that simply defines getter and setter methods for an ivar with the same name:

```
# This line...
attr_accessor :hello

# ...is equivalent to these
def hello
  @hello
end

def hello=(value)
  @hello = value
end
```

The effect of `set_instance_variable` code that you'll need to undo is therefore:

1. Creating the getter `var`
2. Creating the setter `var=`
3. Initializing the ivar `@var` with the value inside the `value` parameter

Note that `set_instance_variable` method does all of these in the **controller instance** context, not the controller class context (despite the confusing `class_eval`).

You will have to do something like this to undo all of the above:

```
def unset_instance_variable(var)
  rendering_controller.remove_instance_variable("@#{var}") if instance_variable_defined?("@#{var}")
  rendering_controller.class_eval { remove_method(var) } if rendering_controller.respond_to?(var)
  rendering_controller.class_eval { remove_method("#{var}=") } if rendering_controller.respond_to?("#{var}=")
end
```

If you want to avoid monkey patching, consider sending this method the `rendering_controller` as a parameter.

Comment: Thanks for this answer, very helpful. I know it's neater, but removing the `ivar` would presumably be irrelevant if the getter is removed as nothing beyond the `rendering_controller` would have access to the value?

Comment: Depends on what the library is doing, and how the controller behaves. If the only magic is done with respond_to? to find usage then you don't need to remove the ivar. But if there is some code depending on value of the ivar than you'll have a problem. I recommend to make things clean once, and then you won't need to worry about weird bugs.